# security in yaml file

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

Hello I follow [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html#using-the-symfony-yaml-component) tutorial and load my custom configure file. Still I want to use some hash inside of it ( so the password or some sensitive data is not white text ) I know there is some encoders build in Symfony 2 but how can I use it inside of my custom yaml file or create my own hash and undo hash function ? Or inside of my controller after load yaml

```
    test
       loginTest:test 
       passTest:test{# how can i hash this ?#}

encoders here ????
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not put password directly in YAML files but store them, along with other sensible data, in `parameters.yml` and access them in your `yaml` file with % notation.

```
// app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    myPass: my_secret_pass


// app/config/config.yml
test
   loginTest:test 
   passTest:  {% myPass %}
```

In this way you can have a different password for each environment and you don't share them